# How to target -moz-opacity property

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mozilla

Usually we target CSS opacity using:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').style.opacity="1";
```

How can I target `-moz` extensions? I have tried using:

```
var moz = document.getElementById('wrapper').style.-moz-opacity="1";
```

But the script gets stuck while doing so. I want to do it in pure JavaScript.

Comment: mozilla is not using -moz for opacity anymore, why use it?

Comment: You can not target -moz or -webkit, better to use two different css class and add or alter them.

Comment: @SudipPal actually you can, its style.MozOpacity but like i said mozilla is not using anymore

Comment: Why dont you define two classes and change the class for the element instead of changing particular style

Comment: @Ark So what? Have you read the question? `How can I target -moz extensions?` Who knows, maybe the OP wants the old FF support in his page. Do you still think that my answer was invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/opacity):

> Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5) and later do not support `-moz-opacity` and
>   support for `MozOpacity` in javascript was removed in Gecko 13. By now,
>   you should be using simply `opacity`.

So what previously was:

```
var opacity = document.getElementById("wrapper").style.MozOpacity;
```

Now is:

```
var opacity = document.getElementById("wrapper").style.opacity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the same camel case you use for say z-index "style.zIndex"? "style.MozOpacity", the M is capital because it starts with a - which skips for the first lower casing. But new FF browsers won't have this property.

http://jsfiddle.net/kNbhg/3/

```
<div id="demo" style="-moz-opacity:1.0"></div>

var str = "";
var elm = document.getElementById("demo");
for(var p in elm.style)
    str += p + " " + typeof(elm.style[p]) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

document.getElementById('wrapper').style["-moz-opacity"]="1";

"style" is simply an object, so you should be able to call it with the square bracket notation.